alt+enter does not recognize the Function interface
If I type:
()->"foo"

and give alt+enter, I choose "Introduce local variable" and intellij gives:
final Supplier<String> stringSupplier = () -> "foo";

But if I type
i->i+1

and give alt+enter, and choose "Introduce local variable", then intellij does not recognize the Function interface (intellij gives other interfaces from our application).
What should I do in intellij so that the Function interface is given by intellij? A setting? Maybe this also relates to other functional interface then Function as well?

What programming language do you use?

@Nadia Tarashkevich Java.

It's not supported by IDEA at present. I've created a feature request for this:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-361893/Introduce-local-variable-should-suggest-for-Function-expression
